# How do you get the Scope in PDFlib

Tags: pdflib

I'm just starting out in PDFlib, and the manual (for PDFlib 8) says to get the scope ...

> You can query the current scope with the scope parameter.

But I have no idea how to get at that parameter, and internet searches are getting me nowhere because "get scope" is everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but I found that this seems to work...

```
myPDF.get_parameter('scope', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently use the following construct in PHP:

```
PDF_get_string($p, PDF_get_option($p, 'scope', ''), '')
```

Explanation: `PDF_get_option` gets the current scope as an integer, and then `PDF_get_string` resolves that integer to a nice string. This return something like "template" or "page".

If you use PDFLib object oriented, the code is probably something like this:

```
$p.get_string($p.get_option('scope', ''), '');
```

And it should be easy enough to adapt it to Java.